# How is default zoom for photos set?

Tags: iphone, sdk

I am in the middle of creating a custom background page with simple UIImage inside a UIImageView.

What I am trying to do is to be able to fit my image the way photos app handles images.

- for default portrait camera pics :  seems like an aspectToFill?
- for default landscape camera pics : aspectToFit for whole page (320,480)
- other custom saved pics: ???

Here, I want to avoid as much empty space possible without hurting how images are perceived to the users.

Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: i ended up just zooming it with setTransform:CGArrineTransformMakeScale ()

Answer (score 0):

you must use aspectFit if you want to see the whole image, at the correct aspect ratio.

you are assuming that its aspectFill for portrait. But that'd be true only for a portrait image being viewed in Portrait (or a landscape image viewed in landscape).

Comment: i dont't need to see the whole image, 
if you the photo app for a portrait camera photo, it is zoomed in to fit the whole package. when zoomed out, there is a blank at the top and bottom. 
so here, my questions is the default zoom level for the default photo app

Comment: if I undertand your reply right, you must use the aspectFit with zoom level 0